# Border-bottom not visible for overflowed row in Grid

Tags: html, css, grid, overflow

I am using grid to present table.
Applied overflow-x to auto, it is working fine but content which is being overflowing isn't rendering border-bottom.

FYI, border bottom is visible for whatever part is showing without overflow.

Codesandbox linnk - *https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/grid-overflow-issue-ckjz5n?file=%2Findex.html%3A38%2C15*

[image: Issue]

[image: Issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix is to select the cell not the row like this.

```
.tableHeaderCell {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(103, 102, 102);
}

.tableBodyCell {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(192, 192, 192);
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

This is a live preview: [Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/grid-overflow-issue-forked-6493l6?file=%2Fstyles.css%3A8%2C1-18%2C1)
But I suggest using the table, th, tr, and td HTML tags it makes the code more clean and easier to work around it. This is a cool documentation for it: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Comment: I knew this workaround, just wondering if you know what was the main cause for that to happen?

Comment: So, I am not sure @AshishGahlot but I think because by default 100% which to border takes the width of is without the overflow so when there is an overflow it doesn't continue. For example if you create a div the height for it is 100%, and you set the body to be more than `10 vh` then the div won't continue. I hope you understand.